# RDD spark.default.parallelism equivalent for Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

## Question

Is there "spark.default.parallelism" equivalent for SparkSQL DataFrame for the narrrow transformation (map, filter, etc)?

### Background

Apparently, parition control is different between RDD and DataFrame. Dataframe has **spark.sql.shuffle.partitions** to control partitions for shuffing (wide transformation if I understand correctly) and "spark.default.parallelism" would have no effect.

[How Spark dataframe shuffling can hurt your partitioning](https://medium.com/@manuelmourato25/how-spark-dataframe-shuffling-can-hurt-your-partitioning-28d05fdcb6fa)

> But what does shuffling have to do with partitioning?
>   Well, nothing really if you are working with RDDs…but with dataframes, that’s a different story. ... As you can see the partition number suddenly increases. This is due to the fact that the Spark SQL module contains the following default configuration: spark.sql.shuffle.partitions set to 200.

The article below suggests **spark.default.parallelism** would not work for Dataframe.

[What is the difference between spark.sql.shuffle.partitions and spark.default.parallelism?](https://intellipaat.com/community/25208/what-is-the-difference-between-spark-sql-shuffle-partitions-and-spark-default-parallelism)

> The spark.default.parallelism is the default number of partitions in RDDs returned by transformations like join, reduceByKey, and parallelize when not set explicitly by the user. But the spark.default.parallelism seems to only be working for raw RDD and is ignored when working with data frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The narrow transformations (`map`, `filter`) preserve the number of partitions, which is why there is no need for a parallelism setting. A setting only makes sense for transformations that may affect the number of partitions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If wide operation may change partitions numbers, is there a spark.sql.shuffle.partitions equivalent setting for RDD. I suppose for RDD, spark.default.parallelism applies to both, but Spark introduced a capability to separately set for narrow and wide respectively for DataFrame. Is this correct?

Comment: "Narrow" transformations don't change partitions anywhere. DataFrame transformations become RDD transformations under the covers. The benefit of using DataFrame transformations is (a) whole stage codegen and (b) better optimization. Use RDDs as directly as little as you possibly can.